# Hooking with JMP instruction and calling convention?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, x86, hook, calling-convention

I'm hooking a 32-bit C++ function by overwriting its first 6 bytes with a `JMP` instruction.

When testing it sometimes (but not always) crashes if the functions don't have the `__stdcall` calling convention. No crashes with `__stdcall`, so far.

This made me wonder if the `JMP` trick works only with certain calling conventions, or does it work with all of them?

I'm using VS2008 on Windows.

Comment: `JMP` modifies no registers nor the stack so it should always work. I suspect your problem is in what happens next.

Comment: Your replacement function has to adhere to the calling convention of the original function, including expectations for stack cleanup, etc.

Comment: @JoeZ Yes, they have the same calling convention. I use templates to make sure the 2 function pointers are the same type. The problem is that this crash happens sometimes, and disappears after recompile I think.

Comment: Are some functions actually smaller than 6 bytes?

Comment: @JoeZ I was wondering about that, too. It's possible, but I'm not sure how to see their size.

Comment: The next time you get a crash, you might pop the code into a disassembler and take a look.  You should also be able to compare whether the original and replacement functions actually do the same stack cleanup, etc.